# Retrieve primary key from table with HQL

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, hql

I have a table that is | **CustomerId** | CustomerName | CustomerCountry |.

How can I write an HQL query to retrieve the CustomerId that corresponds with the combination of a CustomerName and a CustomerCountry?

here is my CustomerDaoImpl:

```
@Repository
public class CustomerDaoImpl implements CustomerDao {

@Autowired(required=true)
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public Customer getCTID(String customerName, String customerCountry) {
    return (Customer) 
this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(/* Some query that gets CTID corresponding to customerName and customerCountry*/);

}
}
```

I want to use this CustomerId and insert it into my DeliveryTable for a new delivery. I am using a DTO for the form where the delivery information is entered and I will be using a DeliveryService for creating the new delivery that uses a CustomerService to retrieve the CustomerId with a CusomerDAO.

Thank you for your help,
D

Comment: This is a very basic query. What have you tried? Have you read http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is Nitin's answer using named parameters which is preferable as JB Nizet pointed out:

```
Long id = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(
   "select customerId from Customer where customerName = :name and customerCountry = :country")
   .setParameter("name", customerName).setParameter("country", customerCountry).uniqueResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand there is a 1:N relation with the Customer:Delivery. It would be beneficial if you used a many-to-one mapping rather than a using the ID directly.

If you still want the HQL you can use

```
this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(
    "from Customer customer where customer.customerName = :name "
    + " and customer.customerCountry = :country").setParameter("name",customerName).setParameter("country",countryName).uniqueResult();
```

`uniqueResult` as I assume customerName + Country is unique in DB. if not you need to use `.setMaxResult(1)` or else the mapping from a `List` to `Customer` will give an error.

Comment: Thanks! I have the tables mapped using a many-to-one mapping but since I want the user to not have to know the CustomerId I have created a DTO with Product, CustomerName, CustomerCountry and Date. What I am trying to do is use the customer name and country to get the customerId (which all already exist in the DB) so that i can insert the customerId in my delivery table for the new delivery. (Hope that was clear) Your assumptions regarding the relations are correct :)

Comment: -1 for using concatenation instead of (named) query parameters. This opens the doors to HQL injection attacks, and will lead to invalid HQL if, for example, the customerName id O'Reilly..